# Match folder in URL path but exclude parameters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match URLs using the folder path /c/ but exclude and URL with the same folder path containing a parameter. There are a lot so the parameter exclusion need to be for all or a wildcard solution.

For example

```
| URL | Regex Result |
| -------- | -------------- |
| https://www.example.com/c/apples/pears    | include|
| https://www.example.com/c/apples/pears?sort=low   | Exclude|
| https://www.example.com/c/apples/pears?taste=sweet   | Exclude   |
```

I'm trying to achieve this in Google Search Console, so it would need to be in the Re2 syntax.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the particulars of re2, but here you go:

```
^https://www.example.com/c/[^?]*$
```

Translation:

- `^` starting at the start of the string
- `https://www.example.com/c/` Match this exact string
- `[^?]*` match any number of characters which are NOT a question a mark
- `$` match all the way to the end of the string

Comment: I'm new to regex, is it the ^ in the square brackets defining the "non-match"? I always thought ^ meant must begin with? (Not questioning just trying to learn haha!)

Comment: Yes.... its very confusing.... basically the contents of the square brackets defines a "character set" and the syntax inside them is totally different than outside.